# Do not have the Unity 3D option at login

Tags: 11.10, unity, login-screen

I am not receiving the Unity 3D option when logging into Ubuntu 11.10.  The only options I have are GNOME, GNOME Classic, GNOME Classic (No effects), Ubuntu, and Ubuntu 2D.  I ran the test `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` . Here are the results:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc

OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 

OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 7.11

Not software rendered:    yes

Not blacklisted:          yes

GLX fbconfig:             yes

GLX texture from pixmap:  yes

GL npot or rect textures: yes

GL vertex program:        yes

GL fragment program:      yes

GL vertex buffer object:  yes

GL framebuffer object:    yes

GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

I even tried the solutions mentioned at [No Unity 3D Option on the login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69930/no-unity-3d-option-on-the-login-screen), but I am still not able to log into Unity 3D.

Under *System Info --> Graphics* the driver is listed as **Intel Sandybridge Mobile** and experience as **Standard**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ubuntu* is Unity 3D and *Ubuntu 2D* is Unity 2D. What do you get if you use the *Ubuntu* option?

Comment: Oh, did not know that.  Ubuntu is the option that is selected by default and the one that I've been using.  Thanks for the help.